Unable to add text box with background color in ffmpeg
I have a video on which I want to have a text box on top of the video for this purposes I am using ffmpeg's following code `import subprocess
def byte():
video = "assets/byte/bite.mp4"
command = [
"ffmpeg",
"-i", video,
"-filter_complex",
"[0:v]drawtext=text='name of the person':fontcolor=black:x=20:y=20:enable='between(t,0,10)'[text];"
"color=white:s=2000x50:d=10[bg];"
"[bg][text]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,10)'",
"-map", "0:v",
"finalbite.mp4"
]
subprocess.run(command)
return "finalbite.mp4"
byte()
`
But the code is returning a video file containing just a white stripe with video frame dimensions as of that white line and video duration of input video
I am wondering what might be wrong ?

You draw text on video and overlay on color=white. Change chains to: ...complex "color=white...,drawtext=...[text]; [0:v][text]overlay.... And remove -map 0:v

still not working. the code is producing a video with only a white horizontal bar in the whole video with the sound of the video and a black background.

try this filter chain: color=white:s=2000x50:d=10, drawtext=text='name of the person':fontcolor=black:x=20:y=20:enable='between(t,0,10)'[text]; [0:v][text]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,10)'
